# Node.js math computation - child process and complex data?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to solve problem where I'm doing a math computation on main thread and I want to move it into child process. The problem is that I can't come up with an simple solution how to do that.

Here's what I have already:

1. I investigated child_process.exec
2. Managed to pass and return simple data to and from the process (like Fibonacci seq)

Problem that I can not solve:

1. My calculation uses array of objects (like: `[{x: 1, y: 2, z: 3}, ...]`)
2. child_process.exec can only pass command line arguments
3. I can not figure out how can I pass complex data structures to child process?

Maybe there is a library that can abstract all this logic and I could do something like:

```
doHeaveComputation(function (result) { 
  //do something with result
});
```

Thank you for help

Comment: Try `child_process.fork()`

Comment: I would accept your anwser if it wasn't comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try child_process.fork(). It returns `ChildProcess` object with `send` method, which allows to send serializable data and sockets to child process. Also you can receive messages from child processes with `message` event.

More in docs: http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_send_message_sendhandle